# How to retrieve only the newest data from firestore snapshot? | Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I can succesfully listen to realtime data from the cloud_firestore sdk:

```html
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(_userId).snapshots().listen((event) {
        event.data().forEach((key, value) {});
      });
```

This listener is triggered if a .onwrite happens in the database. The problem is I don't know which data is new and which already existed before the refresh. I know that firestore sends you only the new entry and the rest will be send from cache.

The docs show an example:

```html
 snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "modified") {
                console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "removed") {
                console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
```

But how can I do it in flutter, because .docChanges does not seem to exist?

I just want to have the new entries because of app performance reasons.

Thus my question is: Where can I see whether an entry is new or cached in flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to record how many documents you got last time and save it "lastDocument" variable and use this code so it will only show the documnets after the limits.

```
_querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .startAfterDocument(lastDocument)
        .getDocuments();
```

Comment: Thank you creator space, this is a smart approach for getting an '.add' entry, but I would also like to know '.modified' and '.removed' entries. Do you know any solutions for those two?

Comment: LIke you meant you want the data of how many got added and deleted, is it